# Is there a way to figure out the return type of a function?

Tags: r, function, types

I think this is a simple question.

As for many languages, you need to provide the return type before you write a function.
however I didn't find solution for R.
the only way I can do right now is to make a call, and using str(),mode(),class() to check the returned value.

but if the function takes long time, I can't use this way
Is there a simple way to know the return type of the function even before I call it?

by the way, I could find some of return type by typing ?function_name, but many helps didn't mention the return type of the function.

Okey, this is the senario why known this info could be so useful:

1.I need the return type to see, after I got the return value, how should I deal with the return, for simple case, if I don't know the return type is list or dataframe, I don't actually have the info to decide which function to use next~Sometimes you don't know you got S3 or S4 object, which made you don't know you should use @ or $ to deal with it

2.suppose there are two functions in two package do the same thing, one return me a connection and another return me a html object, if I knew the return type then I can easily pick which function I should use based on my case. Sometimes you only have limit times to connect to some places, then you will waste several of your chances to check out the return type

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not perfectly defined in R. If the documentation is unclear, your only options are to read the source, read tutorials, and look at somebody else's use of the function.

Comment: The better question to ask is, why do you need the return type? You very rarely need to know this when programming in R.

Comment: I need the return type to see, after I got the return value, how should I deal with the return, for simple case, if I don't know the return type is list or dataframe, I don't actually have the info to decide which function to use next~Sometimes you don't know you got S3 or S4 object, which made you don't know you should use @ or $ to deal with it

Comment: So suppose there are two functions in two package do the same thing, one return me a connection and another return me a html object, if I knew the return type then I can easily pick which function I should use base on my case. Sometimes you only have limit times to connect to some places, then you will waste several of your chances to check out the return type

Comment: You should put that into your question, rather than leaving it as a comment. There are ways to do this in R, although they happen at runtime rather than compile-time (which strictly speaking doesn't apply in R)

Comment: It's really bad that the `Value` section of the doc is not standardized though... I guess some text mining could be done to extract some or most automatically but I just checked a few examples and even the base package is terribly inconsistent.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yes, and it is not the first time I didn't find reliable value info in any help document

Answer (score 2):

In R, there are a number of ways to handle multiple return types from a function.

Let's say you have a function `f` that calls `g`, which can return various types. Your first option is with an explicit type check:

```
f <- function(x)
{
    ...
    y <- g(x)
    if(is.data.frame(y))
    {
        # process result as a data frame
    }
    else if(is.list(y))
    {
        # process y as a list
        # this must go after is.data.frame, because a list is also a data frame
    }
    ...
}
```

Now `f` will check the result of `g` when it returns, and then call the appropriate code to handle it.

This is fine if you only have a small number of possible types to choose from. Once the number of types becomes large, it's a better option to use something more systematic. That option would be to use R's object framework(s). The simplest framework is S3, so let's look at that.

```
f <- function(x)
{
     y <- g(x)
     f_result(y)
}

# this is the f_result _generic_: it dispatches individual methods based on the class of y
f_result <- function(y)
{
     UseMethod("f_result")
}

# f_result _method_ for data frames
f_result.data.frame <- function(y)
{
     # process result as a data frame
}

# f_result method for lists
f_result.list <- function(y)
{
     # process result as a list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short no...

R is a dynamically typed language and many of it's function return different types depending on the parameters passed, being this in my opinion one of the strong points of R, many functions accept many types and return many types. A quick example:

```
mode(sapply(vector(mode="list", 10) ,function (x) return ('a')))
[1] "character"
mode(sapply(vector(mode="list", 10) ,function (x) return (1)))
[1] "numeric"
```

Here sapply returns a "character" type or a "numeric" type depending on the function passed to apply on each of the elements. Overall you just have to get used to the language and if nothing works do what you are doing on small tasks first.

Comment: In the example above it goes even further that I forgot to mention. sapply is taking a "list" as it's first parameter and a "clojure" in its second parameter, but the type of the return values is different.

Comment: Yeah, but  sometimes you have only a few chance, say you only have permission to connect to some server 3 times, and you need cost one time to check the return type...terrible,in other language we knew the return type so we don't even need to call it, we know how to deal with the response